# Animating textPath element

Tags: animation, svg, svelte, transition

I made a text-along path outside a circle, and when I clicked the `next` button, the circle changes size randomly. I already made the circle transition smoothly. But I also want the text/textPath element also animating smoothly. As far as I know, SVG text can't be transitioned(?), are there any work around?

code in svelte:

```
<script>
    let r = 100
    let bez = 4*(Math.sqrt(2)-1)/3*r
    let cx = 250
    let cy = 200
    
    function next() {
        r = Math.random() *100
        bez = 4*(Math.sqrt(2)-1)/3*r
    }
    
</script>

<svg>
    <g>
        <circle cx="{cx}" cy="{cy}" r="{r*0.9}" opacity="0.05"></circle>
        <path stroke="cornflowerblue" 
                    stroke-dasharray="4"
                    fill="none" 
                    d="M{cx},{cy-r} 
                         C{cx+bez},{cy-r} {cx+r},{cy-bez} {cx+r},{cy} 
                         C{cx+r},{cy+bez} {cx+bez},{cy+r} {cx},{cy+r} 
                         C{cx-bez},{cy+r} {cx-r},{cy+bez} {cx-r},{cy}
                         C{cx-r},{cy-bez} {cx-bez},{cy-r} {cx},{cy-r}"
                    id="circle-text"></path>
        <text fill="red">
            <textPath href="#circle-text" >
                Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
            </textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
<button on:click={next}>
    next
</button>

<style>
    svg {
        width:500px;
        height:400px;
        background-color:lightgrey;
    }
    circle {
        transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
    path {
        transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
    text {
        transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
    textPath {
        transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
</style>
```

REPL link: https://svelte.dev/repl/fa34814ccacb4ce7a27fb40dc7c7a493?version=3.55.1

Comment: For me, it is animating (Firefox 110). What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Different (unwanted) behaviour in Chromium

Comment: @ccprog I just realized it's working on firefox. But need to work on all platform though

Comment: you could try reporting it as a [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the value of `r` a [tweened](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tweened) value and then make `bez` a reactive declaration instead of setting it in your `next` function.

This way you're not relying on CSS to animate the transition of values and instead smoothly updating the values yourself. You can also lose all of the CSS transition rules. Here's an example in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/cb4f278c0f2e4c899467bd19bae08e65?version=3.55.1).

```
<script>
    import {tweened} from 'svelte/motion'
    import {quartInOut} from 'svelte/easing'
    const r = tweened(100, {
        duration: 500,
        easing: quartInOut
    })
    $: bez = 4*(Math.sqrt(2)-1)/3*$r
    let cx = 250
    let cy = 200

    function next() {
        $r = Math.random() *100
    }

</script>

<svg>
    <g>
        <circle cx="{cx}" cy="{cy}" r="{$r*0.9}" opacity="0.05"></circle>
        <path stroke="cornflowerblue" 
            stroke-dasharray="4"
            fill="none" 
            d="M{cx},{cy-$r} 
                C{cx+bez},{cy-$r} {cx+$r},{cy-bez} {cx+$r},{cy} 
                C{cx+$r},{cy+bez} {cx+bez},{cy+$r} {cx},{cy+$r} 
                C{cx-bez},{cy+$r} {cx-$r},{cy+bez} {cx-$r},{cy}
                C{cx-$r},{cy-bez} {cx-bez},{cy-$r} {cx},{cy-$r}"
                id="circle-text"></path>
        <text fill="red">
            <textPath href="#circle-text" >
                Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
            </textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
<button on:click={next}>
    next
</button>

<style>
    svg {
        width:500px;
        height:400px;
        background-color:lightgrey;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm still learning the concept of tweening and store/subscription, didn't have a good grasp on it. But thanks it's working as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could also animate/transition the `textPath` adding an `<animate>` element.

```
    <animate href="#circlePath" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" dur="1s" fill="freeze" 
to="M 50 5
      a  45 45 0 0 1  0 90
      a  45 45 0 0 1  0 -90
      " 
from="M 50 5
      a  45 45 0 0 1  0 90
      a  45 45 0 0 1  0 -90" />
```

We're defining start end end states by `from` and `to`attributes.

Each time, the new path data is randomized, we need to update the `from` and `to` values accordingly and restart the animation via  [`animate.beginElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement).

#### Plain JS example

```js
let r = 50
let cx = 50
let cy = 50;

function changeRadius(){

  let min=0.5;
  let max= 1.5;
  let scale = +(Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);
  r = 50 * scale;
    
  let d= circlePath.getAttribute('d');
  
  let newD = `M ${cx } ${cy -r}
  a  ${r} ${r} 0 0 1  0 ${r*2}
  a  ${r} ${r} 0 0 1  0 -${r*2}
  `;
  
  // update smil animation element
  let animate = svg.querySelector('animate');
  animate.setAttribute('to', newD );
  animate.beginElement();
  circle.setAttribute('r', r);


  // update pathdata d attribute after animation 
  animate.addEventListener('endEvent', e=>{
      animate.setAttribute('from', newD);
      circlePath.setAttribute('d', newD); 
  });
  
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:2em
}

svg{
  overflow:visible;
  width:10em;
  margin:2em;
}


button{
  cursor:pointer;
}

circle{
transition:r 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="changeRadius()">change radius</button></p>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g>
    <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" opacity="0.05" />
    <path id="circlePath"
stroke="cornflowerblue" 
stroke-dasharray="4" 
fill="none" 
d="M 50, 0
a 1 1 0 0 1 0 100
a 1 1 0 0 1 0 -100"/>

    <animate href="#circlePath" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />

    <text fill="red">
      <textPath id="textPath" href="#circlePath">
        Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/05a98739eed8439fbec7a2413dbed3f1?version=3.55.1)

See this answer [by Robert Longson: "SVG animate path's d attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191300/svg-animate-paths-d-attribute#8192621)